# Python pandas concatenation

Tags: python, csv, pandas, concatenation

I am downloading data and writing them to CSVs which are later read into python. Once in python (using pandas.read_csv), specific columns of data are meant to be concatenated. However, sometimes the data I'm downaloading into the CSVs is not available ultimately resulting in a non-existent CSV file. When the file is missing, the concatenation process (pandas.concat) chokes due to "NameError: 'xyz' is not defined." Is there a way for pandas.concat to ignore missing data like this?

My script below

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5

import pandas
import time
import os

GFS = pandas.read_csv('/home/user/NWP/TEXT/GFS/PJMS/' + time.strftime("%Y%m%d") + '/' + 'PJMS_GFS_temps.csv', index_col=1)
ARW = pandas.read_csv('/home/user/NWP/TEXT/ARW/PJMS/' + time.strftime("%Y%m%d") + '/' + 'PJMS_ARW_temps.csv', index_col=1)
HRDPS = pandas.read_csv('/home/user/NWP/TEXT/HRDPS/PJMS/' + time.strftime("%Y%m%d") + '/' + 'PJMS_HRDPS_temps.csv', index_col=1)
NAM4 = pandas.read_csv('/home/user/NWP/TEXT/NAM4/PJMS/' + time.strftime("%Y%m%d") + '/' + 'PJMS_NAM4_temps.csv', index_col=1)
GFSMOS = pandas.read_csv('/home/user/NWP/TEXT/GFSMOS/PJMS/' + time.strftime("%Y%m%d") + '/' + 'PJMS_GFSMOS_temps.csv', index_col=1)
ICON = pandas.read_csv('/home/user/NWP/TEXT/ICON/PJMS/' + time.strftime("%Y%m%d") + '/' + 'PJMS_ICON_temps.csv', index_col=1)


COMP = pandas.concat([GFS['PJMS GFS Temp'], ARW['PJMS ARW Temp'], HRDPS['PJMS HRDPS Temp'], NAM4['PJMS NAM4 Temp'], GFSMOS['PJMS GFSMOS Temp'], ICON['PJMS ICON Temp']], axis=1)

path = "/home/user/NWP/TEXT/COMPOSITES/" + time.strftime("%Y%m%d")
COMP.to_csv(os.path.join(path,'PJMS_ALL_temps.csv'))

exit()
```

And an example of the CSV. They are all formatted the same way.

```
,Date,SHD Temp,HEF Temp,OFP Temp,NTU Temp,PGV Temp,ROA Temp,ADW Temp,PJMS GFS Temp
0,2017040101,47.93,44.87,51.53,58.37,59.09,50.27,47.21,51.073885
1,2017040102,47.75,45.59,51.35,58.01,57.47,50.45,45.77,51.058891
2,2017040103,46.85,45.05,51.17,57.11,56.39,49.19,46.31,50.441292999999995
3,2017040104,46.85,45.23,50.09,55.85,56.03,49.01,46.31,49.91994100000001
4,2017040105,47.21,42.71,49.91,54.77,54.23,49.01,46.13,48.67237900000001
5,2017040106,47.75,43.79,50.09,53.69,53.15,49.73,45.41,48.780829
6,2017040107,47.93,44.51,49.55,53.15,52.25,50.09,44.51,48.728466999999995
7,2017040108,48.11,44.87,49.01,52.43,51.53,50.27,44.33,48.527857000000004
8,2017040109,48.29,45.95,48.83,51.53,50.99,50.09,43.97,48.578959000000005
9,2017040110,48.83,48.11,48.11,51.17,50.81,49.37,43.97,49.049803000000004
10,2017040111,48.83,48.11,47.21,50.99,50.63,48.29,45.23,48.790405
11,2017040112,49.37,47.39,49.19,52.25,52.43,48.11,47.03,49.451023000000006
```

And here is the resulting error

COMP = pandas.concat([GFS['PJMS GFS Temp'], ARW['PJMS ARW Temp'], HRDPS['PJMS HRDPS Temp'], NAM4['PJMS NAM4 Temp'], GFSMOS['PJMS GFSMOS Temp'], ICON['PJMS ICON Temp']], axis=1) Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in  NameError: name 'GFSMOS' is not defined

Comment: You need to show your code and en example of your data

Comment: A non-existent file would raise. A completely empty file would raise. If you aren't getting an exception, either the file isn't empty, or you're catching the error and suppressing it. Show us your code and data.

Comment: added code and data

Comment: What does the GFSMOS csv file look like?

Comment: In this instance it does not exist since the data from the source was not available.

FileNotFoundError: File b'/home/user/NWP/TEXT/GFSMOS/PJMS/20170401/PJMS_GFSMOS_temps.csv' does not exist

>> Associated python error

Comment: What would you like to have happen? Just skip concatting that data?

Comment: Yes, that would be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple fix would be to check for the column(s) you care about. Here's some code that investigates various things related to `read_csv`.

```
import pandas as pd

try:
    df = pd.read_csv('nosuchfile.csv')
    print("df=",df)
except Exception as e:
    print("no file raised:", e)

try:
    f = open('empty.csv', 'w')
    f.close()
    df = pd.read_csv('empty.csv')
    print(df)
except Exception as e:
    print('empty file raised:', e)

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6]})
print(df)

if 'a' in df:
    print("yes a")
else:
    print("no a")

if 'xyz' in df:
    print("yes xyz")
else:
    print("no xyz")
```

The output looks like this:

```
no file raised: File b'nosuchfile.csv' does not exist
empty file raised: No columns to parse from file
   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
yes a
no xyz
```

Which tells me that your input csv files aren't empty/nonexistent (since you didn't ask about those errors), and also that you can just use the Python `in` operator to check for a column in advance.

(Of course, EAFP, so you could just catch the exception and go from there...)

**Update**

Based on the comment, I modified your code to store things in a dictionary, indexed by the obvious string names, instead of in separate variables. This makes it easier to process, and easier to manipulate with loops.

The modified version ignores FileNotFound errors, and simply skips over data that isn't available. I don't know if this is actually useful, but it seems to be what you were asking for.

```
import pandas
import time
import os

Csv_fmt = "{home}/TEXT/{type}/PJMS/{timestamp}/PJMS_{type}_temps.csv"
Home_dir = os.environ('HOME')
Timestamp = time.strftime("%Y%m%d")

# Note: ordering here taken from your concat statement.
Temp_types = "GFS ARW HRDPS NAM4 GFSMOS ICON".split()

Temp_dataframes = {}

for temp in Temp_types:
    try:
        path = Csv_fmt.format(home=Home_dir, type=temp, timestamp=Timestamp)
        df = pandas.read_csv(path, index_col=1)
        Temp_dataframes[temp] = df
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File not found: ",temp)
        pass

Col_fmt = 'PJMS {} Temp'

concat_cols = [Temp_dataframes[tt][Col_fmt.format(tt)] for tt in Temp_types if tt in Temp_dataframes]
COMP = pandas.concat(concat_cols)

#COMP = pandas.concat([GFS['PJMS GFS Temp'], ARW['PJMS ARW Temp'], HRDPS['PJMS HRDPS Temp'], NAM4['PJMS NAM4 Temp'], GFSMOS['PJMS GFSMOS Temp'], ICON['PJMS ICON Temp']], axis=1)

path = "/home/user/NWP/TEXT/COMPOSITES/" + time.strftime("%Y%m%d")
COMP.to_csv(os.path.join(path,'PJMS_ALL_temps.csv'))

exit()
```

Comment: Had to tweak the Home_dir line (Home_dir = os.environ["HOME"]) and COMP line (COMP = pandas.concat(concat_cols,axis=1)) but after that, this works exactly how I need it to. Thanks!